# Not able to add multiple clients to this java chat

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, chat

I'm trying to build a simple chat application with multiple clients and a single server using java, but I can't seem to have more than one client type at a time.

Everything works fine when there is just a client and a server.

However when I try to add a second client things go awry.

The second client is able to make a connection, but then the it seems something in the streams portion of the code is blocking as the code doesn't proceed past the setupStreams point in the second client.

This is the client:

```
package instantMessanger;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyleContext;



 public class ClientRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Client client = new Client("127.0.0.1"); //using local host
        client.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        client.startRunning();
    }
}

public class Client extends JFrame{

    /**
     * An Instant Messaging Client
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTextField userText;
    private JTextPane chatWindow;
    private JScrollPane sPane;
    private ObjectOutputStream output;
    private ObjectInputStream input;
    private String message = "";
    private String serverIP; 
    private Socket connection;
    private String ClientUserName; 

    //constructor
    public Client(String host){
        super("Client Instant Messanger");
        serverIP = host;
        userText = new JTextField();
        userText.setEditable(false);
        userText.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                        sendMessage(event.getActionCommand()); //takes text from text area and sends it
                        userText.setText("");
                    }
                }
        );
        add(userText, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        //chatWindow = new JTextArea();
        chatWindow = new JTextPane();
        sPane = new JScrollPane(chatWindow);
        add(sPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setSize(600, 300);
        setVisible(true); 
    }

    //start
    public void startRunning(){
        try{
            connectToServer();
            setupStreams();
            whileChatting();
        }catch(EOFException e){
            showMessage("\n Client terminated the connection ");
        }catch(IOException i){
            i.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            cleanUp();
        }
    }

    //connect to server
    private void connectToServer() throws IOException{
        showMessage("Attempting connection... \n");
        connection = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(serverIP), 6879);
        showMessage("Connected to: " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
    }

    //generate username with random (unique) number
    private void generateUserName(){
        ClientUserName = "CLIENT"+ (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * ( 10 ));
    }

    //set up streams to send and receive messages
    private void setupStreams() throws IOException{
        output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        output.flush();
        input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
    }

    //while chatting with server
    private void whileChatting() throws IOException{
        generateUserName();
        ableToType(true);
        do{
            try{
                message = (String) input.readObject();
                showMessage("\n" + message);
            }catch(ClassNotFoundException c){
                showMessage("\n user input not accepted");
            }
        }while(!message.equals("SERVER - END"));
    }

    //clean up
    private void cleanUp(){
        showMessage("\n Closing the chat!");
        ableToType(false);
        try{
            output.close();
            input.close();
            connection.close();
        }catch(IOException i){
            i.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }

    //send message to server
    private void sendMessage(String message){
        try{
            output.writeObject(ClientUserName + " — " + message);
            output.flush();
            showMessage("\n" + ClientUserName + " — " + message);
        }catch(IOException ioE){
            appendToPane(chatWindow, "\n Error sending message", Color.RED);
        }
    }

    //change + update chatWindow
    private void showMessage(final String message){
        System.out.println("the message is: " + message + " ends here");
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
                //create the thread
                new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        if(message.contains("CLIENT")){
                            appendToPane(chatWindow, message, Color.blue); //append the message to the history
                        }else if(message.contains("SERVER")){
                            appendToPane(chatWindow, message, Color.MAGENTA); 
                        }else{
                            appendToPane(chatWindow, message, Color.green); 
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    //allow user to type into text box
    private void ableToType(final boolean tof){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
                new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        userText.setEditable(tof);
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    //append to pane
    private void appendToPane(JTextPane tp, String msg, Color c)
    {
        StyleContext sc = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
        AttributeSet aset = sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.Foreground, c);

        aset = sc.addAttribute(aset, StyleConstants.FontFamily, "Lucida Console");
        aset = sc.addAttribute(aset, StyleConstants.Alignment, StyleConstants.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);

        int len = tp.getDocument().getLength();
        tp.setCaretPosition(len);
        tp.setCharacterAttributes(aset, false);
        tp.replaceSelection(msg);
    }



}
```

And this is the server:

```
package instantMessanger;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyleContext;

public class ServerRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Server server = new Server();
        server.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //close when hit x
        server.startRunning(); //run the server class
      }
   }

public class Server extends JFrame{

    /**
     * An Instant Messaging Server
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3671904040330502199L;
    private JTextField userText;
    private JTextPane chatWindow;
    private ObjectOutputStream output;
    private ObjectInputStream input;
    private ServerSocket server;
    private Socket connection;
    private String text = "";

    //constructor
    public Server(){
        super("Server Instant Messanger");
        userText = new JTextField();
        userText.setEditable(false); //before connected to anyone else, can't type
        userText.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                        sendMessage(event.getActionCommand()); //send the text when enter is hit
                        userText.setText(""); //after the text is sent, message field goes back to blank
                    }
                }
        );
        add(userText, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        chatWindow = new JTextPane();
        add(new JScrollPane(chatWindow));
        setSize(600, 300);
        setVisible(true); 
    }

    //set up and run the server
    public void startRunning(){
        try{
            server = new ServerSocket(6879, 100); //port num is first arg
            while (true){
                try{
                    //connect and have conversation
                    waitForConnection();
                    setupStreams();
                    whileChatting();
                }catch(EOFException eofException){
                    //when host ends the connection, throw and catch exception
                    showMessage("\n Server ended the connection");
                }finally{
                    cleanUp();
                }
            }
        }catch(IOException ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //wait for connection, then display connection info
    private void waitForConnection() throws IOException{
        showMessage("Waiting for someone to connect ... \n");
        connection = server.accept(); //accept a connection and create socket 
        new ThreadedSocket(connection).start();
        showMessage("Connected to: "+ connection.getInetAddress().getHostName() );
    }

    public class ThreadedSocket extends Thread {
        Socket socket;
              ThreadedSocket( Socket socket ) {
                this.socket = socket;
              }
    }

    //get stream to send and receive data
    private void setupStreams() throws IOException {
        output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream()); // stream for send message 
        output.flush();
        input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream()); //stream for receive message
    }

    //during the chat conversation
    private void whileChatting() throws IOException{
        ableToType(true); //allow the user to type
        do{
            try{
                text = (String) input.readObject();
                showMessage('\n' + text);
            }catch(ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException){
                showMessage("\n user input not accepted");
            }       
        }while(!text.contains("END")); //if user types END, end convo
    }

    //close streams and sockets after done to cleanup
    private void cleanUp() {
        showMessage("\n Closing connections..... \n");
        ableToType(false);
        try{
            output.close(); //close input
            input.close();  //close output
            connection.close();  //close the connection     
        }catch(IOException ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //send a message to the client
    private void sendMessage(String message){
        try{
            output.writeObject("SERVER - " + message); //replace server with username?
            output.flush(); //flush the buffer
            showMessage("\nSERVER - " + message);
        }catch(IOException ioException){
            appendToPane(chatWindow,"\n Error: Message not sent", Color.red);
        }
    }

    //update the chatWindow
    private void showMessage(final String text){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( //create a thread that updates the GUI
                new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        if(text.contains("CLIENT")){
                            appendToPane(chatWindow, text, Color.blue); //append the message to the history
                        }else if(text.contains("SERVER")){
                            appendToPane(chatWindow, text, Color.MAGENTA); 
                        }else{
                            appendToPane(chatWindow, text, Color.green); 
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    //let the user type when connected
    private void ableToType(final boolean tof){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( //create a thread that updates the GUI
                new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        userText.setEditable(tof); //set to passed in true or false
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    //append to pane
    private void appendToPane(JTextPane tp, String msg, Color c)
    {
         StyleContext sc = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
         AttributeSet aset = sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.Foreground, c);

         aset = sc.addAttribute(aset, StyleConstants.FontFamily, "Lucida Console");
         aset = sc.addAttribute(aset, StyleConstants.Alignment, StyleConstants.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);

         int len = tp.getDocument().getLength();
         tp.setCaretPosition(len);
         tp.setCharacterAttributes(aset, false);
         tp.replaceSelection(msg);
     }


}
```

Any and all help would be appreciated!

Comment: From what I see your server cannot handle more than one client at a time - your threading code looks non-functional to me.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use one variable for all connections to the server. This won't work as the previous connections will be garbage collected once you create a new socket connection. When accepting a new connection, add it to a list instead. I won't provide a code example as this would require changes to most parts of the code and would bloat the answer.

Note that it will also require you to make a separate input/output stream for each connection, whereas right now you are overwriting the previous connection's streams once a new connection is established.